# How do I scroll within HTML rather than in the View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have a WebView, which displays an HTML page with a toolbar div, followed by a long text div. The toolbar div should be always visible, so it's defined as position fixed.

On a Nexus 4, and Note 2 it's all fine. However there is a problem running it on an ICS Galaxy Tab. Everything displays OK, but touching a toolbar button behaves as if it's the content div that has received the touch event instead of the toolbar.

I'm assuming this is a bug in ICS, perhaps on this specific device. So I'm looking for a workaround where instead of the scrolling taking place within the Android layout, the scrolling is done with the HTML page. That way I can simply have two consecutive divs which won't overlap, and hence shouldn't be susceptible to the suspected bug.

How do I tell Android to scroll within the html, rather than within the layout?

**LAYOUT FILE**

> ```
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:orientation="vertical"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> tools:context=".WebviewActivity1" >
>  <WebView
>     android:id="@+id/webView1"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" >   
>  </WebView> 
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

**HTML**

```
<body>
 <div id='toolbar' style='position: fixed; top:0px; width: 100%; z-index:99">
    toolbar
 </div>
 <div id='scrollable_content' style="overflow-y: auto; z-index:1>
     lorem ipsum
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. You say the toolbar needs to be at the top so it's `position: fixed`, which suggests the scrolling is already taking place internally within the WebView (so "within the HTML").

Comment: Currently the webview is scrolling the whole page, eg. position 0,0 of the HTML is being scrolled off the top of the display. I want the page to be fixed, and the div to scroll within the page, eg position 0,0 of the page is always at position 0,0 of the display. I think I've figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I've figured it out.
The problem is that because my HTML page was growing taller than the display, whatever I did, the WebView was scrolling it.

To prevent the WebView from scrolling, I first had to constrain the height of my HTML to the height of the viewport. Once I did that, there was nothing for the WebView to scroll, so I'm getting the effect I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquerymobile.com/toolbar/  You'd then have the support of the corporations that support jquerymobile if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the WebView to scroll set it's height to wrap_content:  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`